# ASP.NET redirect rule for .cfm file

Tags: asp.net

I have a DotNetNuke application where I am migrating all my old web sites all together under portals.
As users are storing old sites URLs into bookmarks, I need to write redirect rules so they can get properly on new page.

Now, at one point I stuck because I am unable to write rule.

My condition is 
URL A
http://www.mydomain.com.cn/auto.cfm?myurl=domain/notice_article.cfm
Should redirect to
http://www.mynewdomain.com/home.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented this using redirectMaps.

e.g.

```
<rewriteMap name="MyRedirectMap_Entire">
    <add key="whttp://www.mydomain.com.cn/auto.cfm?myurl=domain/notice_article.cfm" value="http://www.mynewdomain.com/home.aspx" />
  </rewriteMap>
```

Adding this properly under web.config file, I able to redirect properly.

Comment: Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)